# Setting a conditional breakpoint in Dyalog RIDE

Tags: debugging, apl, dyalog, dyalog-ride

In [Dyalog RIDE](https://github.com/Dyalog/ride), I know how to set breakpoints that will halt execution on specific lines in the APL source. Is there a way to make a breakpoint conditional so I can stop at a line only if a particular set of conditions are met, e.g. `0<+⌿⍵`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no IDE (or RIDE) support for this, but with a simple change to the source code, you can achieve the effect.

In a tradfn:

```
    :If 0<+⌿var
  :Endif
```

In a dfn:

```
    0<+⌿⍵:{
  }⍬
```

If the condition doesn't hold, we skip the line that would have stopped execution.