# Resuming execution after conditional breakpoint in Dyalog APL

Tags: debugging, apl, dyalog, dyalog-ride

In a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76304695/setting-a-conditional-breakpoint-in-dyalog-ride) I asked about how to set a conditional breakpoint in Dyalog RIDE, and the accepted answer works as advertised, by creating a guard statement with an empty function call as the body. Execution will be halted on the expected line when the condition is met. However, this being a guard, if I then want to resume execution, the function will return, which is not what I want -- is it possible to resume execution as if the guard statement had not been triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply skip the currect line before resuming execution.

By default, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will skip the current line, both in the cross-platform RIDE and in the Windows-only IDE.

If this is something you do often, then consider combining the line skipping and resumption of execution into a single function key, here <kbd>F7</kbd>:

**IDE:** `'FD' 'RM'⎕PFKEY 7`

**RIDE:** Edit > Preferences… > Shortcuts > "PF7": `<FD><RM>`

Comment: Think you could also do →⎕LC+1

Comment: @Silas That should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

A single, older, cross-platform way is to branch to the next line with `→⎕LC+1`

[⎕LC](https://help.dyalog.com/18.2/index.htm#Language/System%20Functions/lc.htm) is a vector of the line numbers where you're suspended, so will have the line you stopped as the first element. Incrementing this and then branching(jumping) there will resume execution at the next line.